# Not getting the correct square root returned

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

With a array that holds [1,2,2], I am getting 2,497... returned instead of 3.

I am trying to take the power of each value in the array, combine the values together and then square root the result. What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT: Trying to do it all in one line.

```
a = a.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2)).reduce((acc, v) => Math.sqrt(acc + v, 0));
```

Comment: Why do you expect 3?

Comment: Hint: how many times do you *expect* to be calling `Math.sqrt`, and how many times are you *actually* calling it?

Comment: I expect 3 because (1^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 ) = 9. Then the square root of that should be 3.

Comment: That's not what the code does. Instead it runs `√(√(√(1+0,0)+4,0)+4,0)`

Comment: 2.497 = sqrt(sqrt(5) + 4).  You want to call the square root after completing the reduce step.

Comment: You need to look how reduce work. This implementation is wrong @Azzi

Comment: @sveyda Yeah, I realize I kinda did something dumb here. I know what reduce does, but I confused myself trying to fix this and make it work, and ended up doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to calculate the square root of the final sum:

```js
const myCalc = a => Math.sqrt(a.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v * v, 0));

console.log( myCalc([1, 2, 2]) ); // 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm trying to do it in one single line. If that is possible at all.

Comment: @Azzi like this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1,2,2]
a = Math.sqrt(a.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2)).reduce((acc, v) => { return acc + v}),0);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think about using return.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.sqrt(a.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x ** 2, 0))
```